# progress bar for avoiding blankscreen in android

Tags: android, progress-bar

iam  new to Android and Stackoverflow,i need some help regarding to develop a progress bar in my android app.I have two activities, while passing intent from 1st activity to 2nd iam trying to display progress bar between two activities.Now doubt : is it possible to place progress bar  before the SetContentlayout of 2nd activity.As I have more number of table layouts in 2nd activity & it is taking time to load.I tried many example of Stackoverflow but didn't get out of this issue.please help regarding this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_products);      
         Intent subprointent=getIntent();
```

Any help would be suggestable.thankyou.

**Edit**:
here is my 1st activity code:

```
public class FrontPage extends Activity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_front_page);
    grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
     grid.setColumnWidth( 170 );
     grid.setVerticalSpacing(20 );
     grid.setStretchMode( GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH );
     grid.setNumColumns( GridView.AUTO_FIT );

     grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Intent subprointent=new Intent(FrontPage.this,SubProducts.class);
                startActivity(subprointent);

                  // your loading code goes here


        } 

     });



}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_front_page, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

here is 2nd Activity code:

```
public class SubProducts extends Activity {
private ProgressDialog pdlg;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_products);      

         Intent subprointent=getIntent();


        /* if (progDailog.isShowing()) {
                progDailog.dismiss();
            }*/

        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.subbutton);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Dialog settingsDialog = new Dialog(SubProducts.this);
                settingsDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                settingsDialog.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cust_toast_layout , null));
                settingsDialog.show();
            }

         });

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_sub_products, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: hey buddy. you can use add the tablelayouts async. and till then you can show the progressbar.

Comment: you are getting blank screen because you are doing to much of work in your UI thread in onCreateView. Move the processing to an Async task. Start the progress bar in onCreate and finish it when your processing ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at splitting up your layout then. Put your main layout as just a place holder. Finish executing onCreate and then in your onStart() start the progess bar and load the table layouts a child view of the main activity view.

Your activity_sub_products layout should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/placeholderView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then create a layout called something like myTableViews.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
>  //put all your table views here
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Then override the onStart() in your activity and do

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
 super.onStart();
 showProgressBar("Loading...");
 LinearLayout rlView =  (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.placeholderView);
  rlView.addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myTableViews, null));
}
    public synchronized void  showProgressBar(final String message){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    if(pdlg == null){
                        pdlg = new ProgressDialog(MyAcitivity.this); 
                        pdlg.setCancelable(false); 
                        pdlg.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER); 
                    }
                }catch (Exception e) {}

                try{
                    if(!pdlg.isShowing()) pdlg.show();
                    pdlg.setMessage(message); 
                }catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        });

    }
```

You need to move

```
Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.subbutton);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Dialog settingsDialog = new Dialog(SubProducts.this);
                settingsDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                settingsDialog.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cust_toast_layout , null));
                settingsDialog.show();
            }

         });
```

To the end of onStart()

Comment: a small EDIT in above answer is under onStart() I need to call super.onStart();

Answer (score 0):

here's a great tutorial regarding asynctask and progress bar: [link](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/)

you should display the progress bar while doInBackground and release it in onPostExecute

Comment: hi ranco..I dont have any background code to run in doInBackground but i just want to display the progress bar before loading the xml..any idea?

Comment: in that case I guess @Premsuraj answer will be more relevent

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way which worked for me I hope this may work for you...
Take an AsyncTask in your first activity and perform your second activities operations in `protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)` method and then call your intent i.e. startActivity();

```
class hello extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
       ProgressDialog dialog=null;
       Intent i;

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() 
   {


           dialog=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"PLEASE WAIT","LOADING CONTENTS  ..",true);
   }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
            if(dialog.isShowing())
                    {
                       dialog.dismiss();

                    }           
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {

        // Perform your task Here and then call intent
        i = new Intent(MainActivity.this , Countries.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Happy coding;)